# Database field Enum to C# List

Tags: c#, mysql, database, list, enums

In my database I have a Enum field. I want to put those Enum attributes in a List in C#.
I searched but I couldn't find the answer. Is this possible?
I use a MySqlDatabase. If I want to get the rows from the database I use:

```
using (var uow = new UnitOfWorkScope<TrackerEntities>(UnitOfWorkScopePurpose.Reading))
```

In my application I use the Entity Framework

Comment: What kind of database? MySql?

Comment: What type of data access are you using?

Comment: Also accept some answers to some of your questions. You have 12 unaccepted questions.

Comment: I updated my question. And sometimes I can't accept some answers because there isn't one. Sometimes I fixed my own questions but I must wait 2 days to answer it and then I forget to update it.

Answer (score 1):

if you loading data in a data reader, however this is `sql-server` way. But point here is to convert `string` into `enum`

```
var list = new List<YourEnumType>();

var field= reader["DBFieldName"] != DBNull.Value ? reader["DBFieldName"].ToString()
                                                   : "";
var myField=(YourEnumType) Enum.Parse(typeof(YourEnumType ), field);    

list.Add(myField);
```

Also have a look at [The ENUM Type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html)

Comment: I don't use a reader. I have a Entity Framework

Comment: @Jeffrey: Have you seen [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/05/tip-23-how-to-fake-enums-in-ef-4.aspx)??

Comment: @Jeffrey, this is why I asked *What type of data access are you using*. If you only ask half a question your answers are not going to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make a query against the schema table to list the enum values.

```sql
SELECT COLUMN_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLE_NAME AND 
      COLUMN_NAME = @COLUMN_NAME
```